# How to move a non-boot partition from one drive to another?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a 1TB drive that I used to store files. OS is on an SSD, and I just purchased a 2TB drive.

How can I move the partition on the 1TB to the 2TB so that I don't mess up any program installations/preserve the drive letter/etc so that I can then use the 1TB for backup?

Comment: Don't worry about messing up drive letters; After the files are copied, you can reassign drive letters to make them match up with what they need to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to do the following:

1. Connect both drives
2. Create a new partition on the 2TB drive that takes up the entire drive
3. Clone the old partition from the 1TB drive to the new partition on the 2TB drive
4. Verify that your files are on the cloned partition
5. Reboot into safe mode
6. Reassign/Change the drive letter of the old partition to one that is not in use
7. Reassign/Change the drive letter of the new partition to the letter that the old partition was using
8. Resize the new filesystem to consume the entire partition
9. Reboot

The new partition should now be in the old drive letter, and appear in every way identical except for free space, which should now be much larger :)

The old partition is now mounted on a different drive letter, and already seeded as a backup!